# Is there a reasonable notion of "free asymmetric tensor" generalising the concept of free functor?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I've been looking at free functors again and I had an idea inspired by call by push value and substructural logic.

Given a category $\text C$, instead of just creating a free functor $\text{F}: \text{Set} \rightarrow \text C$ is there a reasonable notion of free asymmetric tensor $\otimes : \text{Set} \times \text C \rightarrow \text C$ ?

My intuition is that if you think of a free functor as a monad and then as an effect system it's natural to ask if you can think of the same idea but in terms of substructural logic.

I think the appropriate laws assuming a terminal object $\text{i} \in \text C$ would include:

$$\text{F} = - \otimes \text{i}$$

Associativity

$$ \text{assoc}: x \otimes y \otimes z \leftrightarrow (x \times y) \otimes z $$

Left unit

$$ \text{lunit}: \cdot \otimes x \leftrightarrow x$$

I tried playing around a bit with the idea but I think I need help.

I think I want to think of the free functor to the category of endofunctors over $\text C$?

```
Require Import Coq.Unicode.Utf8.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Classes.SetoidClass.

Module Import Term.
  Class Term := {
    T: Type ;
    Term_Setoid: Setoid T ;

    one: T ;
    zero: T ;
    prod: T → T → T ;
    sum: T → T → T ;

    prod_one_left A: prod one A == A ;
    prod_one_right A: prod A one == A ;
    prod_assoc A B C: prod A (prod B C) == prod (prod A B) C ;

    sum_zero_left A: sum zero A == A ;
    sum_zero_right A: sum A zero == A ;
    sum_assoc A B C: sum A (sum B C) == sum (sum A B) C ;

    prod_zero_left A: prod zero A == zero ;
    prod_zero_right A: prod A zero == zero ;

    prod_sum_left A B C: prod (sum A B) C == sum (prod A C) (prod B C) ;
    prod_sum_right A B C: prod C (sum A B) == sum (prod C A) (prod C B) ;

    (* Fixme add distributivity *)
    prod_Proper: Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) prod ;
    sum_Proper: Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) sum ;
  }.
  Coercion T: Term >-> Sortclass.

  Existing Instance Term_Setoid.
  Existing Instance prod_Proper.
  Existing Instance sum_Proper.

  Notation "0" := zero.
  Notation "1" := one.

  Infix "*" := prod.
  Infix "+" := sum.
End Term.

Module Import Hom.
  Class Homomorphism {A B: Term} (map: A → B) := {
    map_one: map 1 == 1 ;
    map_zero: map 0 == 0 ;
    map_prod x y: map (x * y) == map x * map y ;
    map_sum x y: map (x + y) == map x + map y ;

    map_Proper: Proper (equiv ==> equiv) map ;
  }.
  Existing Instance map_Proper.

  Definition Hom (A B: Term) := { f: A → B | Homomorphism f}.
  Definition Hom_Homomorphism {A B} (f: Hom A B): Homomorphism (proj1_sig f) := proj2_sig f.

  Existing Instance Hom_Homomorphism.

  #[program]
   Definition id A: Hom A A := λ x, x.

  Next Obligation.
  Proof.
    exists.
    all: intros.
    all: try reflexivity.
    intros ? ? p.
    auto.
  Qed.

  #[program]
  Definition compose {A B C} (f: Hom B C) (g: Hom A B): Hom A C := λ x, f (g x).

  Next Obligation.
  Proof.
    exists.
    all: intros.
    - repeat rewrite map_one.
      reflexivity.
    - repeat rewrite map_zero.
      reflexivity.
    - repeat rewrite map_prod.
      reflexivity.
    - repeat rewrite map_sum.
      reflexivity.
    - intros ? ? p.
      rewrite p.
      reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Infix "∘" := compose (at level 30).
End Hom.

(*

Instead of a free functor to the category of terms make some sort
of free bifunctor ?

I'm just not sure this quite makes sense.
  *)
Module Free.
  Inductive free {H: Type} {T: Term}: Type :=
  | η (h: H) (t: T)
  | one
  | zero
  | prod (A B: free)
  | sum (A B: free)
  .
  Arguments free: clear implicits.

  Inductive equiv {H T}: relation (free H T) :=
  | reflexive: reflexive (free H T) equiv
  | symmetric: symmetric (free H T) equiv
  | transitive: transitive (free H T) equiv

  | prod_one_left A: equiv (prod one A) A
  | prod_one_right A: equiv (prod A one) A
  | prod_assoc A B C: equiv (prod A (prod B C)) (prod (prod A B) C)

  | sum_zero_left A: equiv (sum zero A) A
  | sum_zero_right A: equiv (sum A zero) A
  | sum_assoc A B C: equiv (sum A (sum B C)) (sum (sum A B) C)

  | prod_zero_left A: equiv (prod zero A) zero
  | prod_zero_right A: equiv (prod A zero) zero

  | prod_sum_left A B C: equiv (prod (sum A B) C) (sum (prod A C) (prod B C))
  | prod_sum_right A B C: equiv (prod C (sum A B)) (sum (prod C A) (prod C B))

  | η_Proper h: Proper (SetoidClass.equiv ==> equiv) (η h)
  | prod_Proper: Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) prod
  | sum_Proper: Proper (equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) sum
  .

  Existing Instance η_Proper.
  Existing Instance prod_Proper.
  Existing Instance sum_Proper.

  Instance free_Equivalence H T: Equivalence (@equiv H T) := {
    Equivalence_Reflexive := reflexive ;
    Equivalence_Symmetric := symmetric ;
    Equivalence_Transitive := transitive ;
  }.

  Instance free_Setoid H T: Setoid (free H T) := {
    equiv := equiv ;
  }.

  Instance free_Term H T: Term := {
    T := free H T ;

    one := one ;
    zero := zero ;
    prod := prod ;
    sum := sum ;

    prod_one_left := prod_one_left ;
    prod_one_right := prod_one_right ;
    prod_assoc := prod_assoc ;

    sum_zero_left := sum_zero_left ;
    sum_zero_right := sum_zero_right ;
    sum_assoc := sum_assoc ;

    prod_zero_left := prod_zero_left ;
    prod_zero_right := prod_zero_right ;

    prod_sum_left := prod_sum_left ;
    prod_sum_right := prod_sum_right ;

    prod_Proper := prod_Proper ;
    sum_Proper := sum_Proper ;
  }.
  Infix "⊗" := free_Term (at level 60, right associativity).

  Definition map_h {T A B} (op: A → B): free A T → free B T :=
    fix loop p :=
      match p with
      | η x t => η (op x) t
      | one => one
      | zero => zero
      | prod A B => prod (loop A) (loop B)
      | sum A B => sum (loop A) (loop B)
      end.

  (* FIXME define Term homomorphism *)
  Definition map_t {H} {A B: Term} (op: A → B): free H A → free H B :=
    fix loop p :=
      match p with
      | η x t => η x (op t)
      | one => one
      | zero => zero
      | prod A B => prod (loop A) (loop B)
      | sum A B => sum (loop A) (loop B)
      end.

  (* FIXME seems wrong *)
  Definition ε_h {A B: Term}: free A B → A :=
    fix loop p :=
      match p with
      | η x _ => x
      | one => 1
      | zero => 0
      | prod A B => loop A * loop B
      | sum A B => loop A + loop B
      end.

  Definition ε_t {A} {B: Term}: free A B → B :=
    fix loop p :=
      match p with
      | η _ y => y
      | one => 1
      | zero => 0
      | prod A B => loop A * loop B
      | sum A B => loop A + loop B
      end.

  (* FIXME seems wrong *)
  Definition join {A B T}: A ⊗ (B ⊗ T) → B ⊗ T := ε_t.

  #[program]
  Fixpoint push {A B C} (p: (A * B) ⊗ C): A ⊗ (B ⊗ C) :=
      match p with
      | η ab t => η (fst ab) (η (snd ab) t)
      | one => one
      | zero => zero
      | prod a b => prod (push a) (push b)
      | sum a b => sum (push a) (push b)
      end.

  Instance push_Proper {A B C}: Proper (equiv ==> equiv) (@push A B C).
  Proof.
    intros ? ? p.
    induction p.
    all: cbn in *.
    all: try reflexivity.
    - symmetry.
      auto.
    - rewrite IHp1, IHp2.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_one_left.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_one_right.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_assoc.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite sum_zero_left.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite sum_zero_right.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite sum_assoc.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_zero_left.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_zero_right.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_sum_left.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite prod_sum_right.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite H.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite IHp1, IHp2.
      reflexivity.
    - rewrite IHp1, IHp2.
      reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Instance push_Homomorphism {A B C}: Homomorphism (@push A B C).
  Proof.
    exists.
    all: cbn.
    - reflexivity.
    - reflexivity.
    - intros ? p.
      reflexivity.
    - intros ? p.
      reflexivity.
    - intros ? ? p.
      rewrite p.
      reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Definition pop {A B C} (p: A ⊗ (B ⊗ C)): (A * B) ⊗ C.
  Admitted.
End Free.
```

Comment: A free functor comes as the adjoint to a forgetful functor $U:C\to \mathrm{Set}.$ Do you assume such a $U$ here?

Comment: Yeah the main trouble is coming up with a sensible forgetful functor. Either there is a pair of forgetful functors $\text U: \text C \rightarrow \text{Set} * \text C$ or it consumes an endofunctor which is even weirder $\text U : [\text C, \text C] \rightarrow \text{Set}$. You would assume adjoint to a tensor type would be some sort of function type but I dont quite get what $\text{ev} : A \otimes [A, B] \rightarrow B$  would mean. Not sure what the best "forgetful bifunctor" would be.  $\text{U} : \text{Set}^{\text{op}} \times C \rightarrow C$ seems unjustified and strange.